Cannot use suspend resume with 24.04 - loss of icons, launcher and activities
I recently updated from 22.04 to 24.04.  There many missing parts of the desktop upon resume from suspend.  Only the top banner (log out, settings, etc.) is displayed.  Desktop icons are all missing, the launcher is missing and activities is missing.  I have to log out and log back in to get the desktop with icons, launcher and activities.  Or I have to restart. This is what I see after resume:

Hardware Model: ASUS ROG STRIX B550-F GAMING_WIFI_ ;
Processor: AMD Ryzen 5 5600x12 ;
Memory: 16.0 GiB ;
Kernel 6.8.0-45-generic ;
Windowing: Wayland ;
Gnome Version: 46 ;
Graphics card: NVIDIA Corporation GM204 [GeForce GTX 970] ;
The NVIDIA GPU and suspend-resume have been troublesome with past Ubuntu versions, but the problems were fixed with suggestions from other users.  I suspect this problem is also related to NVIDIA and have tried numerous suggestions including updating grub, making sure Wayland and not Jammy are in use, etc.
Does anyone have any idea what is wrong?  (I rarely interact with Ask Ubuntu, so apologies if I'm using this forum incorrectly.)

Swapped the NVIDIA card out for Cezanne [Radeon Vega Series / Radeon Vega Mobile Series].  Same problem.  Cannot recover desktop after resume.  I need to log in and out every time, or use Hibernate.

Looking for errors in journalctl during suspend:
Sep 22 14:35:30 karen-System-Product-Name pipewire[2129]: pw.node: (alsa_output.pci-0000_07_00.6.analog-stereo-48) suspended -> error (Start error: No such file or directory)

And looking for errors in journalctl with resume:
Sep 22 14:30:49 karen-System-Product-Name kernel: xhci_hcd 0000:01:00.0: xHC error in resume, USBSTS 0x401, Reinit
Sep 22 14:54:04 karen-System-Product-Name kernel: xhci_hcd 0000:01:00.0: xHC error in resume, USBSTS 0x401, Reinit
Sep 22 15:16:30 karen-System-Product-Name kernel: xhci_hcd 0000:01:00.0: xHC error in resume, USBSTS 0x401, Reinit

Major Progress!  See https://medium.com/@tenebreoscure/ubuntu-24-04-desktop-icons-not-working-1c0d3cb46d67
Following instructions and I get all desktop icons after suspend-resume!  Launcher and Activities still missing, but available by pressing the upper left hand icon (looks like a power icon).

To get the Launcher and Activities panel back after resume, I had to go into the Extensions Manager and turn the dock on.  This works after suspend-resume.  The desktop now has everything.  Pain in the *** to get to this point, but it works.

Here the link to my answer with a solution for this issue: https://askubuntu.com/a/1531176/1665712

I set a bounty on this problem, but ended up fixing it myself today.  Here's what I did.  I blew away the existing DING extension and added GTK4 Desktop Icons NG.  See https://medium.com/@tenebreoscure/ubuntu-24-04-desktop-icons-not-working-1c0d3cb46d67
Then, to get the dock and activities panel back, I installed Dash to Panel available as an extension.  Now it all works great for Suspend-Resume.
